# Cocoapods - Invalid symlinks (Headers) prevents submission to App Store

Tags: macos, swift, cocoapods

I'm getting following error when trying to submit osx application:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Planiro Tracker". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'com.droidlabs.PlaniroTracker.pkg/Payload/PlaniroTracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Headers'
>   which resolves to a location
>   'com.droidlabs.PlaniroTracker.pkg/Payload/PlaniroTracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/Current/Headers'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink -
>   Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'com.droidlabs.PlaniroTracker.pkg/Payload/PlaniroTracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework/Headers'
>   which resolves to a location
>   'com.droidlabs.PlaniroTracker.pkg/Payload/PlaniroTracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework/Versions/Current/Headers'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.

I checked contents of the applications, and all frameworks installed by cocoapods contains invalid "Headers" symlink. Cocoapods version 0.36.4.

I added `mkdir -p "${destination}/$1/Versions/A/Headers"` to Pods-frameworks.sh as temporary workaround, but it's strange that dirs are not created (not sure where it should happen) and maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Header symlink and resubmit.

Worked for me.

Make sure that the folder "headers" is in the root of your framework folder

Make also sure that the binary is in the root folder.

example:
[image]