# iTunes Store app validation error when using pod Google/CloudMessaging

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, objc-bridging-header

I added GCM as google does in their example swift project:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm

1. Library installed via pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
2. Added `#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>` in Bridge-Header.h

After uploading build to iTunes I received this email from Apple:

> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceID.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDConfig.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDConfig.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDDelegate.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDDelegate.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDHeaders.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Private/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDHeaders.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/AdMob-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/AdMob-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/Analytics-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/Analytics-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/AppInvite-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/AppInvite-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/CloudMessaging-Module.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/CloudMessaging-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/CloudMessaging.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging/Public/CloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/Core-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/Core-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/Core.h' which resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/Core.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/GGLConfiguration.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLConfiguration.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/GGLContext+CloudMessaging.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging/Public/GGLContext+CloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/GGLContext.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLContext.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/GGLErrorCode.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLErrorCode.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/GMRConfiguration.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GMRConfiguration.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/SignIn-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/SignIn-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMConfig.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMConfig.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMPubSub.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMPubSub.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMReceiverDelegate.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMReceiverDelegate.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMService.h' which resolves to
>   a location
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMService.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/GoogleCloudMessaging.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Private/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceID.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDConfig.h' which resolves to
>   a location
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDConfig.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDDelegate.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDDelegate.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/GGLInstanceIDHeaders.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID/../../../GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceIDHeaders.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/AdMob-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/AdMob-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/Analytics-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/Analytics-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/AppInvite-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/AppInvite-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/CloudMessaging-Module.h' which resolves
>   to a location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/CloudMessaging-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/CloudMessaging.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging/Public/CloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/Core-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/Core-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/Core.h' which resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/Core.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/GGLConfiguration.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLConfiguration.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/GGLContext+CloudMessaging.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging/Public/GGLContext+CloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/GGLContext.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLContext.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/GGLErrorCode.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GGLErrorCode.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/GMRConfiguration.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public/GMRConfiguration.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/SignIn-Module.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/Google/Google/../../../../Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders/SignIn-Module.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMConfig.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMConfig.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMPubSub.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMPubSub.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMReceiverDelegate.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMReceiverDelegate.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/GCMService.h' which resolves to a
>   location
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GCMService.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/GoogleCloudMessaging.h' which
>   resolves to a location
>   'Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging/../../../GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging.h'
>   that does not exist or is outside of the package.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As advised in this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254478/5832311), try to delete the Header symlink and resubmit. Make sure that the folder "headers" is in the root of your framework folder and that the binary is in the root folder. This related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3418) might also help. It suggested to add `mkdir -p "${destination}/$1/Versions/A/Headers"` to `Pods-frameworks.sh`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To delete the Header symlink, do I have to unarchive build and then delete it? Where is exact place to put mkdir -p "${destination}/$1/Versions/A/Headers" inside Pods-frameworks.sh? Thanks.